# Returns a part of a result (GREP)

Tags: regex, linux, shell, grep

With this command, I would like one command to get the current mac adress only, and another command to get only the permanent mac. So I have to use a grep expression, but I don't know what to do.

```
    $ macchanger -s wlan0
    Permanent MAC: 14:25:47:ff:c4:aa (Twinhan)
    Current MAC: 00:24:54:f0:5c:cc (unknown)
```

So I would really like to do something like macchanger -s wlan0 | grep ... in order to exactly get 14:25:47:ff:c4:aa
And another command to get 00:24:54:f0:5c:cc
Thanks you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the 'Permanent' line:

```
macchanger -s wlan0 | awk '/Permanent/ { print $3 }'
```

To get the 'Current' line:

```
macchanger -s wlan0 | awk '/Current/ { print $3 }'
```

Comment: Thanks, it's the best way of handling the question x) I didn't know awk, it seems really useful.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would be better off using `sed` than `grep`:

```
macchanger -s wlan0 | sed -n '/^Permanent/s/Permanent MAC: \([0-9a-fA-F:]*\) .*/\1/p'
macchanger -s wlan0 | sed -n '/^Current/s/Current MAC: \([0-9a-fA-F:]*\) .*/\1/p'
```

This would work with a POSIX-compliant `sed`; GNU `sed` sometimes has a mind of its own, but it accepts these and works as expected.

Comment: There's no reason to match on `^Permanent` outside the `s///` expression. Just add `^` to the beginning of the `s///` expression's pattern match if you want to ensure that it's anchored.

Answer (score 1):

If you want grep:

```
macchanger -s wlan0 | grep Permanent | grep -P -o '..:..:..:..:..:..'
macchanger -s wlan0 | grep Current | grep -P -o '..:..:..:..:..:..'
```

Answer (score 1):

A single `grep` for each address:

```
grep -P -o '(?<=Permanent MAC: )[a-zA-Z0-9:]+'
grep -P -o '(?<=Current MAC: )[a-zA-Z0-9:]+'
```

Answer (score 0):

The `-o` option to `grep` will do what you want. For example:

```
grep -o '[0-9a-f:]\{17\}'
```

Comment: That would pick up both addresses each time.

Comment: True. I wasn't clear from the original question whether that was desired. edit: Though if I'd read it more carefully I guess it was pretty clear. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This solution depends on the order of the results in the output:

```
declare -a results
results=($(macchangher -s wlan0 | egrep -oi '([a-f0-9]{2}:){5}[a-f0-9]{2}'))
perm=$results[0]
cur=$results[1]
```